# Error :Function must be terminated with a string in CodeIgniter's constants.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

While writing this line :-

`define('APPLICATION_ROOT',  $_SERVER('DOCUMENT_ROOT') );`

in `constants.php` in CodeIgniter framework of PHP i get error `Error :Function must be terminated with a string`. Can i not use Super Global arrays in constants.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an instance of CI up at the moment, but shouldn't that line be:

```
define('APPLICATION_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

(With the square braces instead of parens)

Answer (score 2):

```
define('APPLICATION_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] );
```

Brackets [ ], not parentheses.

Though I will recommend against doing that. Constants are supposed to be, well, constant.
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] might not be defined or the same everywhere you use it.